# Bonds: Is "principal" a synonym of "face value"?

Tags: bonds, financial-literacy, terminology, principal

Consider a bond that has a face value (or par value, or nominal value) of $1000. Suppose I buy this bond at a price of $950. Is this $950 the principal, or is the principal $1000? From my perspective, the $950 is the amount I invested, so I look at it as the principal. However, online articles seem to treat "principal" and "face value" as synonyms. If this is the case, what is the proper term to describe the $950 I invested?

(I am currently learning more about bonds. This question is for clearing up my confusion about bond terminology)

Answer (score 2):

The principal for a vanilla coupon-paying bond is $1,000 regardless of how much you paid for it.  There are some bonds that will have a lower principal value at the beginning and *accrue* principal rather than making coupon payments, but I don't think that's what you're describing.

> If this is the case, what is the proper term to describe the $950 I invested?

I would call that your *cost basis* in the bond. Or perhaps the *present value* at the time you bought the bond.

Comment: "There are some bonds that will have a lower principal value at the beginning and accrue principal rather than making coupon payments..." Are you referring to zero-coupon bonds? For zero-coupon bonds, what is the term for the amount paid to bondholders at maturity? Is it "principal" too?

Comment: Yes, zero-coupon bonds are one of those types. And "principal" is the amount paid at maturity, but if the bonds pays off early (e.g. is called) the amount paid off is still called "principal" but may be lower than the face value (par amount).  Similar to how the principal balance of a mortgage changes over time.

Comment: So face value is not necessarily the same as the principal?

Comment: "face value" is the amount paid _at maturity_. There are some bonds that start with a "principal" amount less than the face value but it grows over time (similar to a zero-coupon bond).

Comment: Could you add that information to your answer so that I can accept it? "principal" vs "face value" vs "cost basis" for vanilla bonds, callable bonds, and zero-coupon bonds.

Answer (score 2):

$950 would be the Price of the Bond that you got it at a discount.
$1000 would be the Principal / Face value ...  that would be used to calculate the interest.